# Push notifications with no sound on MIUI

Tags: java, android, push-notification, miui

My app's main functionality is push-notification messages sent from remote server. I am using FCM as a message delivery service. My problem is that notifications come without any sound on Xiaomi Mi 9 Lite (Android 9/MIUI 11). However, on Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 (Android 9/MIUI 10) sound works fine and on Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge (Android 8) as well. I created MessagingService which extends FirebaseMessagingService and notification channel as written in documentation.


Here is my code:

```
public class MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static String channelId;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private NotificationChannel notificationChannel;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;

    private MessagesViewModel viewModel;

    public MessagingService() { }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        channelId = getResources().getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        final Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.raw.metrial_message_icon);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(false);
        notificationBuilder.setSound(soundUri);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            final AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .build();

            String name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
            String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, name, importance);
            notificationChannel.setDescription(description);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setShowBadge(true);
            notificationChannel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            notificationBuilder.setChannelId(channelId);
        }
        else {
            notificationBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
            notificationBuilder.setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_SMALL);
            notificationBuilder.setLights(Color.WHITE, 500, 5000);
        }

        viewModel = new MessagesViewModel(getApplication());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        logger.info("onNewToken()");
        ConnectionParameters.getInstance().setToken(s);
        MyPrefs.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).putString(Constants.TOKEN, s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        final String messageId = remoteMessage.getData().get("message_id");
        final String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        final String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

        if (messageId != null && title != null && body != null) {

            final Message message = new Message();
            message.setMessageId(messageId);
            message.setTitle(title);
            message.setContent(body);
            message.setTimestamp(new Date());

            try {
                message.setNotificationId((int)viewModel.insert(message));
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            logger.info("onMessageReceived(): notificationId=" + message);

            if (MyPrefs.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getBoolean(Constants.ENABLE_PUSH)) {
                notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
                notificationBuilder.setContentText(body);

                final Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, MessageInfoActivity.class);
                notifyIntent.putExtra(Constants.ARG_MESSAGE_OBJECT, message);
                TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
                stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(notifyIntent);
                PendingIntent pendingActivityIntent =
                        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(message.getNotificationId(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingActivityIntent);

                final Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
                notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND|Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
                notificationManager.notify(message.getNotificationId(), notification);
            }
        }
    }

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
}
```

And in **Settings->Notifications** I got the following parameters:
[image]

And inside my **push-notifications-channel** sound is enabled but whenever a message comes, it seems like app notification settings override parameters in notification channel.
[image]

There should be some solution because in popular apps such WhatsApp, Telegram, etc., these switches are enabled after installation (by default). Hope, someone helps!

Comment: Having the same issue with Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 Global.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As nobody provided better solution, I guess there is no way to allow sound/badge counter/floating notifications programmatically on MIUI (and mostly on other Chinese OEMs). It is a user's privilege to turn these settings on manually. Therefore, to enhance UX, it is important to decrease the quantity of "clicks" as much as possible. So, we could provide a dialog describing how to enable the features above with button leading to App's settings.
Namely, to open a notification settings page through Intent, do the following:

```
final Intent notificationSettingsIntent = new Intent();
notificationSettingsIntent
        .setAction("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");
notificationSettingsIntent
        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    notificationSettingsIntent.putExtra(
            "android.provider.extra.APP_PACKAGE",
            activity.getPackageName());
}
else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        notificationSettingsIntent.putExtra(
                "app_package",
                activity.getPackageName());
        notificationSettingsIntent.putExtra(
                "app_uid", 
                activity.getApplicationInfo().uid);
}
activity.startActivityForResult(
        notificationSettingsIntent, 
        NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE);
```

and you could open a dialog with button "Open notification settings" clicking on which triggers the code snippet above.

Comment: Thanks for your diligence! I could not find other solutions on this issue.

Comment: @wai Ha Lee is there any way to check permission is on or off because if sound is on then i don't want to open dialog again

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot check whether sound was enabled or not. It is possible to check are notifications enabled for the app, however, as far as I know, no way to get result from sound availability.