# Push Notification sound not working in xiaomi

Tags: android, push-notification, xiaomi

Notification sounds are getting suppressed due to Xiaomi sound settings. If Allow sound is toggled off notification sound will not be played. I want to show a popup to the user if this setting is disabled, but I am not able to fetch this setting using Notification manager or Android Manager. How can I fetch this os specific setting so that I can nudge the user?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58715149/push-notifications-with-no-sound-on-miui

Comment: Did you solve this?